# Is it possible to use $_REQUEST for inserting data in a mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I already have this code figured out, but the entries a user submits with the submit button aren't going anywhere. Is there any way to fix this, or should I just use the $_POST method?

PHP code:

```
    <?php
include ("dbroutine.php");
function register() {
$connect = db_connect;
if (!$connect)
{
die(mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db(securitzed, $connect);
if (!$select_db) {
die(mysql_error());
}
//Collecting info
$fname = $_REQUEST ['fname'];
$lname = $_REQUEST ['lname'];
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

//Here we will check do we have all inputs filled

if(empty($_REQUEST['username'])){
die("Please enter your username!<br>");
}

if(empty($_REQUEST['password'])){
die("Please enter your password!<br>");
}


if(empty($_REQUEST['email'])){
die("Please enter your email!");
}

//Let's check if this username is already in use
$user_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = '".$_REQUEST

['username']."'");
$do_user_check = mysql_num_rows($user_check);
//Now if email is already in use
$email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE email= '".$_REQUEST['email']."'");
$do_email_check = mysql_num_rows($email_check);
//Now display errors
if($do_user_check > 0){
die("Username is already in use!<br>");
}
if($do_email_check > 0){
die("Email is already in use!");
}


//If everything is okay let's register this user
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, password, email) 
VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['username']."', '".$_REQUEST['password']."', '".$_REQUEST['email']."', '".$_REQUEST['fname']."', '".$_REQUEST['lname']."')");
if(!$insert){
die("There's little problem: ".mysql_error());
}


}
switch($act){
case "register";
register();
break;
}
```

HTML code:

```
   <body>

        <form method="post">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="" /> <br />
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="" /> <br />
            E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" value="" /> <br />
            Desired Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> <br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> <br />
            Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="passwordconf" value="" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

    </body>
```

If I need to add anything, could anyone point it out, if not, I could also add some extra code if needed.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You shouldn't actually use `$_REQUEST` if you already know it's going to be posted; so you should use `$_POST`.

Comment: If usernames are unique, make them unique in your database table structure; this will eliminate much of the code.

Comment: Using $_POST will work for you, also implements measures to prevent $_POST data from sql injections from going to the db..

Comment: also in your form specify action and method as post..

Comment: I think you would benefit from a little more debugging; there's an issue somewhere, but I doubt we can help you in a practical way without knowing from which point the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_REQUEST` contains: `$_COOKIE`, `$_GET`, and `$_POST` variables. if you use `$_REQUEST` you have no guarantee that the data came from the post data, which leads to security holes in your script. I would use `$_POST` but by using this method you are vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).

`$_GET` retrieves variables from the querystring, or your URL. `$_POST` retrieves variables from a POST method, such as (generally) forms. `$_REQUEST` is a merging of `$_GET` and `$_POST` where `$_POST` overrides `$_GET`.

## Fix

You have to specify the action in your form as below.

```
<form action="fetch_data.php" method="post">

<form action="URL">
```

`URL` - Where to send the form-data when the form is submitted.
Possible values:

- An absolute URL - points to another web site (like
  action="http://www.example.com/example.htm")
- A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like action="example.htm")

Comment: This is useful information, but it should be a comment instead because it doesn't really answer the question. Also, I don't think action is really required, it will use the current page by default.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, I advice you to read more about variables.

**Second**, `$_REQUEST` is a variable like `$_POST`, `$_SESSION`, `$_GET` and so on, which can be stored into your database. So, for your question, Yes you can use `$_REQUEST` to insert data in a MySQL database

HOWEVER, using it as a substitute for the `$_POST` variable is not secure at all and not a good practice. Take a look at [this](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html) to see how the `$_POST` variable works.

**Third**, you are using `mysql_*` functions in your code. please consider using `PDO` or `MYSQLI` instead to prevent SQL INJECTION and secure your website better. In addition, MYSQL is dupricated in PHP 5.5 and up. take a look at [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) tutorial, it shows you how to use PDO instead of MYSQL.

**Fourth**, you should not be storing passwords directly to databases, you need some form of password hashing. read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

- Use `ACTION` in your HTML `form`.
- Sanitize the data as well from `sql` injection.
- Check if data from `$_REQUEST` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    $fname = $_POST ['fname'];
$lname = $_POST ['lname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

You could also do following to check request params

```
var_dump($_POST);
```